# Convergence of the sequence $x_n=\tan x_{n-1}$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm stuck with this problem:

> Consider the sequence $x_n=\tan x_{n-1}$ with arbitrary $x_1$. Does this sequence converge?

I tried to apply Cauchy criterion. We have $|\tan x-\tan y|\ge |x-y|$ for all $x,y$ in the domain of the function $\tan x$, but the domain of $\tan x$ is not "continuous" because it does not contain numbers of the form $n\cdot \frac{\pi}{2}$. So all I can say about this problem is I guess that the sequence diverges, without any logical explanation.

Thank you very much.

Comment: This is likely a dupe...

Comment: Presumably you mean to exclude initial values $x_1$ for which $(\tan \circ \cdots \circ \tan)(x_1)$ is not the domain of $\tan$, so that the sequence is well-defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To complement Robert's idea, assume that $(x_{n})$ converges.

Denoting $L = \lim_{n\to\infty} x_{n}$, then $L$ is a solution of the equation $L = \tan L$. It is not hard to show that $L$ cannot be a half-integer multiple of $\pi$: $L \notin \pi \Bbb{Z} + \tfrac{1}{2}\pi$.

Now let $\epsilon > 0$ be small enough so that

$$ (L-\epsilon, L+\epsilon) \subset (n\pi-\tfrac{1}{2}\pi, n\pi+\tfrac{1}{2}\pi) $$

for some $n \in \Bbb{Z}$, and let $N$ be such that $|x_{n} - L| < \epsilon$ whenever $n \geq N$. Then by the Mean Value Theorem (this is applicable since both $x_{n}$ and $L$ lie in the open interval on which $\tan$ is defined and differentiable),

$$ |x_{n+1} - L| = \left|\tan x_{n} - \tan L\right| \geq \left|x_{n} - L\right|. $$

Since this is true for any $n \geq N$, we must have

$$ |x_{n} - L| \geq |x_{N} - L|. $$

Therefore, in order to have convergence, we must have $x_{N} = x_{N+1} = \cdots = L$. That is, $(x_{n})$ must become eventually constant.

Answer (score 3):

There will be infinitely many initial values $x_1$ such that $x_n$ is eventually constant.  But that's the only way it can converge, because $|\tan(x) - \tan(y)| > |x - y|$ for $x \ne y$ in the same interval $((n-1/2) \pi, (n+1/2) \pi)$ (**not** for all $x$, $y$ in the domain: for example $\tan(n\pi) = 0$ for all integers $n$).